# How to use multiple languages in android app using titanium studio

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am building an app which will support multiple languages. If a user selects one language for ex Japanese, Chinese or Hindi den the complete app should transform into that particular language and whatever values entered in that app should be in that particular language only.

I am using titanium studio (alloy) and I am new to it so can anyone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [internationalization documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Internationalization). Basically you have a strings.xml file for every language and just reference these in your code.

Example Taken from the above link):

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="welcome_message">Welcome to Kitchen Sink for Titanium</string>
</resources>
```

Your controller:

```
var str1 = L('welcome_message');
var str2 = Ti.Locale.getString('welcome_message');
// str1 === str2
```

While you can control the language of all strings in your app it is not applicable to control the language of your user. Because he is free to type whatever he wants you can't effectively control it.

Comment: ... and you can use "L(....)" in your TSS files as well to bind e.g. texts to labels. I do that a lot